# Why obj.save() in django return 'none' even after data is saved in database

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

[image]

contact.save() is triggered and data is also saved in database ,but it return none after saving. Anyone explain. I just want display success or error message for the operation. As it return none it jumps to else block. You can see the output 'none' as i print the contact.save() object.

Comment: First, please use code formatting to enter your code, not an image. 

Second, is this a form save or a model save? If it's a model save, have you overridden the save method on the model? If so, have yo uremembered to call `super`?

Comment: model.save() returns None as far as I can tell - or will raise an exception - why do you get the idea that the save () method will return something ?

Answer (score 1):

If `.save()` ends without any exception it means the object has been saved correctly.

You can do the following:

```py
try:
   contact.save()
   print("Contact %s saved correctly!" % contact.id)
except as e:
   print("Contact could not be saved. Exception thrown: %s" % e)
```

If you want to make `.save()` return the object, check my other answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67582493/override-save-model-django-save-method-with-return/67583648#67583648).