# Override save model Django save method with return

Tags: python, django, model

I have this function, I want to make it a method of a Message model class.

```py
def save_message_to_db(message, message_id):

    mex = Message(
        message_id=message_id,
        subject=message.subject,
        sender=message.sender.address,
        has_attachments=message.has_attachments,
        sent_date=message.sent,
        received_date=message.received
    )
    mex.save()

    return mex
```

I've tried various ways, but still get errors. I need to return, expecially the id of the object saved.

### Update

```
@staticmethod
def save_mex(message, message_id):
    mex = Message(
        message_id=message_id,
        subject=message.subject,
        sender=message.sender.address,
        has_attachments=message.has_attachments,
        sent_date=message.sent,
        received_date=message.received
    )
    mex.save()

    return mex
```

this is the only way I made it work, but this is a work around...
I get the errors in the Pyacharm IDE, I can not understand how to use the super() in this situation, because I want to pass an object and treat it in this method, not args and kwargs.

Comment: Can you show us the methods you have tried so far?

Comment: _What_ error do you get? Add the _full_ traceback of the error to your question.

Answer (score 4):

It should be as simple as this. Simply override the save method of your model and return the instance after the super call.

```py
class YourModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(YourModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs) 
        return self

your_model_saved_instance = YourModel(name='Edoardo').save()
```

You can even make a base model class with this feature and use it in every model you want.

```py
class BaseModel(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BaseModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs) 
        return self

class YourModel(BaseModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

your_model_saved_instance = YourModel(name='Edoardo').save()
```